# Menú bootstrap4 no se despliega

Tags: html5, bootstrap

Estoy haciendo una web responsiva para un proyecto personal, he diseñado el menú y se contrae perfectamente al abrir la web desde el cel, pero al hacer clic no despliega las opciones del menú.

Estoy referenciando los archivos de bootstrap y he agregado al final una hoja de estilo personal para algunos estilos básicos (Color de fondo, color de texto, color en a:hover etc).

No se que no estoy viendo, pero no logro hacerlo funcionar.

Agradecido con cualquier ayuda que puedan brindarme

Mi código

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<!-- bootstrap 4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrap.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Estilos Internos -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/landing.css">
<body>
<!-- Contenedor pantalla fluida -->
<div class="container-fluid">
<header>
  <!-- Menu adaptativo  -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top">
    <!-- Logo-Marca -->
    <img class="navbar-brand" src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
    <!-- Icono 3barras -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- Menu links  -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-success" href="#">Opcion1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Opcion2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Opcion3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Regístrate</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Ingresar</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Busca" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Buscar X</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</main>
<section class="seccion1">
  <p>Seccion1</p>
  <article class="articulo1">
    <header>
      <hgroup>
        <h1>Titulo del articulo</h1>
        <h2>Subtitulo del articulo</h2>
      </hgroup>
      <time datetime="2018-06-20" pubdate>Publicado 20-06-2018
    </time>
    </header>
    <p>Este es el texto del primero mensaje</p>
    <figure>
      <img height="250px" src="images/RoadshareIcono.png" alt="Icono RoadShare">
      <figcaption>
        Esta es la imagen del primer mensaje
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <footer>
      <p>comentarios (0)</p>
    </footer>
  </article>
</section>
<aside class="columna1">
  <blockquote>
    Cita numero 1
  </blockquote>
</aside> -->
<footer class="pie">
  <small>Todos los derechos reservados a <em>Roadshare LLC</em> y <em>Soluciones Tecnológicas ConexVen c.a</em> 2012-2018&#174;</small>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: podrias subir todo el html ?

Comment: No hay mucho más, estoy empezando con el proyecto y empece por el menú principal, de todas formas ahí te va.

Comment: Lo agregue al comentario original. Gracias por adelantado! @LucianoMontañez

Comment: Les tienes que especificar que son dropdown a lo elementos de menu o si no, no te funcionará , mira bien este [ejemplo](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#nav), ve donde está el dropdown y veras que hay que especificar muchas cosas , como el data-toggle y que la etiqueta href tenga como role ="button", no tengo tiempo pero eso te ayudará, Saludos.}

Comment: Para obtener mejores respuestas, deberías subir un [mcve], donde se pueda reproducir el problema. No olvides incluir tu CSS y JS, ya que puede estar sobreescribiendo el de Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brother, hay varios errores.
No cerraste el `<head>` , te falto el inicial`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">`

El navbar lo tenías dentro del container.
También las librerias que estás usando de jquery tienen algún problema, te recomiendo utilizar las que están en el sitio oficial de bootstrap.

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- bootstrap 4 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Estilos Internos -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/landing.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Contenedor pantalla fluida -->
  <!-- Menu adaptativo  -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixe-top">
    <!-- Logo-Marca -->
    <img class="navbar-brand" src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
    <!-- Icono 3barras -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- Menu links  -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-success" href="#">Opcion1
            <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Opcion2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Opcion3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Regístrate</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Ingresar</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Busca" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Buscar X</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <main>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
        aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </main>
    <section class="seccion1">
      <p>Seccion1</p>
      <article class="articulo1">
        <header>
          <hgroup>
            <h1>Titulo del articulo</h1>
            <h2>Subtitulo del articulo</h2>
          </hgroup>
          <time datetime="2018-06-20" pubdate>Publicado 20-06-2018
          </time>
        </header>
        <p>Este es el texto del primero mensaje</p>
        <figure>
          <img height="250px" src="images/RoadshareIcono.png" alt="Icono RoadShare">
          <figcaption>
            Esta es la imagen del primer mensaje
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <footer>
          <p>comentarios (0)</p>
        </footer>
      </article>
    </section>
    <aside class="columna1">
      <blockquote>
        Cita numero 1
      </blockquote>
    </aside> -->
    <footer class="pie">
      <small>Todos los derechos reservados a
        <em>Roadshare LLC</em> y
        <em>Soluciones Tecnológicas ConexVen c.a</em> 2012-2018&#174;</small>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Apenas cambie las librerías empezó a funcionar. muchísimas gracias amigo @hugo-quiñónez, lo del head y el viewport es porque pegando el código aquí me volví un 8, es mi primer vez por aquí, pero si lo tengo en mi código, tengo ahora unos cuantos detalles de estilo que resolver para que quede como deseo, pero al menos ya salí con tu ayuda de lo que me tenía trancado. De nuevo mil gracias!!!

Comment: Excelente! Que bueno que te sirvió.

Comment: Amigo @Hugo de donde saca uno estos valores para las librerías ? integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous">

En la documentación oficial de bootstrap no veo nada de eso.

Comment: Está en el CDN de la página official de bootstrap, https://getbootstrap.com/